# The 'items' element in YouTube Data API search returns nothing when called '/videos'

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Let's say i call the '/videos' search with the following payload:

```js
{
  key: process.env.YOUTUBE_KEY,
  part: 'contentDetails,statistics,snippet',
  id: 'UCo8bcnLyZH8tBIH9V1mLgqQ',
  max_results: "5"
}
```

Then the following is the response:

```js
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "\"Fznwjl6JEQdo1MGvHOGaz_YanRU/ftqcoEi5lFrDLEyLbPZCiTrEzXU\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 0
  },
  "items": [

  ]
}
```

As you can see the items array is empty. I checked, my key is valid and the id is valid too.

Comment: The video id you are using is unavailable or deleted or may be private, it is working with other id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /videos endpoint takes video IDs and you are passing in a channel ID.

Example url to get first video in that channel:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus&id=cV542dRK3uk&key=API_KEY